# SignalR not functioning on server

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have a windows service I made through visual studio in c#.
It uses SignalR to connect to a SQl database and receive notifications.
However, when I deploy the service onto the server itself (Windows Server 2008R2), it doesn't function. This server is the server hosting the SQL server too.

This is a SELF-HOSTED SignalR service. It is not using IIS or anything of the like to run. It is packaged as a simple Windows Service. Therefore, it doesn't have issues with typical MVC, IIS hosted apps (such as /signalr/hubs pathing, web.config etc.)

On my development computer, I use the WAN IP of the sql server to connect to its database. When I run it, it does everything it's supposed to and fires off a notification everytime server changes.

On the server itself, the service installs fine, but doesn't fire off any notifications. I left the IP as the WAN IP for developmental services and was planning to change it to localhost, etc. once it works but it does not.

For now, I left the service running on my development computer, and it's working great. I'd really prefer it to be on the server itself though, since that's the computer that will always be online.

Any hints or ideas on why this works on my development computer but not the server?

Thanks!

[Edit]
I'm using Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2013 as my development setup.
The service is running on localhost:2165 (arbitrary port). I am able to access that address via a web browser on the server itself.

Comment: Can you get to your SignalR server while logged on to the server?  Could it be a firewall issue?

Answer (score -1):

You don't state what your development operating system is, but if you are using WebSockets, then you need to have a minimum of Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012.

From the documentation, the [supported platforms are](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms) (emphasis mine):

> **Supported server IIS versions**
>
> When SignalR is hosted in IIS, the following versions are supported. Note that if a client operating system is used, such as for development (Windows 8 or Windows 7), full versions of IIS or Cassini should not be used, since there will be a limit of 10 simultaneous connections imposed, which will be reached very quickly since connections are transient, frequently re-established, and are not disposed immediately upon no longer being used. IIS Express should be used on client operating systems.
>
> Also note that for **SignalR to use WebSocket, IIS 8 or IIS 8 Express must be used, the server must be using Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, or later, and WebSocket must be enabled in IIS**. For information on how to enable WebSocket in IIS, see IIS 8.0 WebSocket Protocol Support.

Comment: While what you've said is true, it does not answer the question. SignalR will fall back to other protocols if web sockets aren't available, so lack of web socks would not explain the behavior that Clifford is experiencing.